# Find a graph on a torus (tutorial)

Tags: graph-theory

Find the $K_{4,4}$ graph on a torus.

So, that's my homework. I've even found it in one of my textbooks, but only the solution, not a how-to-do-it method.
I would really appreciate a step-by-step guide (I haven't managed to find one on the Internet either).

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: Well, I've filled 3 pages with my toruses, but since I've never seen a problem like this, I don't really know, how to proceed, what to look for.

Comment: Oh--ok.  We get a ton of people here who just ask without trying, so I wanted to ensure you had attempted something. :) Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea with drawing a graph on a torus (or any genus $g$ surface) is try to draw it in the fundamental polygon. For a torus it looks like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e6/KleinBottleAsSquare.svg), and the reason this is the fundamental reason can been seen [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Toroidal_coord.png). With higher genus surfaces the ideas and pictures are similar.

Now you draw the graph on that fundamental region with the property that if your edges hits the blue edge (or red edge), you're allowed to move to the appropriate side like doppz did in the drawing he or she provided. Is there a method to drawing a toroidal graph on this fundamental region? Not one that I've come across. At each step, don't intersect edges ;)

Comment: answer I was looking for. thanks!

Comment: Is this answer correct? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_polygon says the linked fundamental polygon is that of a Klein bottle, not a torus.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I'd like some confirmation, but I believe this works. Sorry for the crude drawing

Comment: but why? how do you figure it out? I already have a solution if I want, I just don't know how to find one.

Comment: I just messed around in paint until I found the solution. Didn't take long. I made use of the properties of a torus, knowing that $K_{4,4}$ is not planar. It's pretty much just a puzzle, I did a lot as a kid. I knew in this case I could wrap lines around the boundaries, so I made sure to use those. The rest just followed.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about it in general, you should also try to get some idea about the face sizes in the graph:

For your case we have a bipartite graph so there are no 3-cycles and we have $n=8$ and $m=16$. Using Euler-Poincaré on the torus we have $n-m+f = 0$ so that $f=8$. Counting around the faces we get a minimum of $4\times 8 = 32$ edges but $2m=32$ so we know that all faces must be 4-cycles.

[image: $K_{4,4}$ on the torus]
Given that it is possible to start with a 4-cycle, say 1,5,2,7 in the diagram and then 5 needs to adjacent to 3 and 4 and since the graph is very symmetrical the pattern suggests itself.